# Finding my timezone name using PHP

Tags: php, timezone

Is there  any way to find my timezone name using PHP?
example:Asia/Kolkata

I have tried using the following service, it works but sometimes I notice that the site is down.
https://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?

Comment: find your timezone name based on what ?

Comment: Define 'my timezone', please. Do you mean your server's timezone, or your timezone, as in, being a visitor of your server, etc.? If the former, then givens answers should do it. If the latter, then it's not that easy. You usually have to resort to asking your visitors explicitly what their timezone is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`date_timezone_get`](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.date-timezone-get.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean get the timezone name based on an offset or based on a given time that doesn't specify a timezone which you want to compare to the GMT, that will be complicated. This is because multiple timezone names have the same offset.

Example: `Europe/Amsterdam` and `Europe/Berlin`

What you can do is write a function that will return an ARRAY of applicable timezone names.

But if this is totally not what you want, and you just want to know on which timezone your PHP is running, just use `date_default_timezone_get()` or `ini_get('date.timezone')` or even just `date('e')`. The abbriviation (example: `CES` for central european time) is kept in `date('T')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
   echo date_default_timezone_get();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

we can't view current timezone..

```
echo print_r(date('O'));
```